# Python, pip: avoid gcc during installation

Tags: python, pip

Our local python package server contains these files:

```
subprocess32-3.2.7-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
subprocess32-3.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
subprocess32-3.5.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
subprocess32-3.5.0.tar.gz
subprocess32-3.5.2.tar.gz
```

The file subprocess32-3.5.2.tar.gz is new.

Before installing of subprocess32 was successful, since this new version exists, it fails. It fails because there is no gcc on the machine which tries to install subprocess32.

What can I do? I think there are these solutions.

- remove subprocess32-3.5.2.tar.gz
- make subprocess32-3.5.2 available as wheel
- make gcc available on the machine
- fix the dependency to subprocess32-3.5.0

But all of them don't really make me happy, since I only solve my current problem. Some weeks later, the same thing can happen again.

Is there a way to tell pip to use a wheel even if this means to take an older version?

Background: there is no explicit dependency on the new version. Pip tries to take the latest version.

I use pip version 9.0.1.

Comment: What version of pip are you using?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I updated the question. Version: 9.0.1

Comment: Shouldn't installing a compiler fix the problem for now and the future?

Comment: Are you trying to make pip “pin” the version of a package? Not sure what solution you are looking for. Once the package is installed, it will not install it again unless there is an upgrade, and if there is one, you can ignore the upgrade. I think there is something here we are missing, like what is triggering pip?

Comment: Wouldn't `--only-binary` (tell pip to not use source packages) be an option for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your use case is to prohibit installation from source distribution (`tar.gz`, `tar.bz2`, `zip`) when installing a particular package `subprocess32`. Do it with

```
$ pip install subprocess32 --only-binary=subprocess32
```

The difference between `--only-binary=pkgname` and `--only-binary=:all:` is that in the first case, the source dists will be forbidden for `pkgname` only, while the latter prohibits source dists for all packages scheduled for installation, including dependencies. Multiple packages can be selected by comma-separating their names, e.g. `--only-binary=spam,eggs,bacon`.

#### Permanent configuration

Entering the `--only-binary` option every time starts to annoy pretty quickly. To apply it permanently, open `pip.conf` and add:

```
# ~/.pip/pip.conf

[global]
only-binary=subprocess32
```

Now issuing `pip install subprocess32` will have the same effect as the above command - the latest binary wheel available for the target platform will be selected. If no binary wheels will be eligible for installation, the command will fail.

#### Specifying binary requirement

You can also force the `--only-binary` option in the requirement file if you have one:

```
# requirements.txt
subprocess32 --only-binary=subprocess32
```

Now, when installing from the requirement file (via `pip install -r requirements.txt`), the latest binary wheel available for the target platform will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently wheels for version 3.2.7 and 3.5.0 so you can try

```
pip install -U subprocess32==3.2.7
```

or

```
pip install -U subprocess32==3.5.0
```

You can also try to disable source at all:

```
pip install -U --only-binary=:all: subprocess32
```